# VB Script to ask for input where a file name would go

Tags: android, vb.net, batch-file

My company is working on creating RSA tokens for Android.  In order to create the token we go through the whole process of creating from the server but then we have to download and convert the token using an application and command-line.

I need assistance in creating a script(batch file) that will allow me to enter the token name instead of having to type in the whole command everytime.

I've started with this so far:

@echo off
c:\Token_Converter\TokenConverter TokenName.sdtid -android -o tokenfile.txt

Command:

TokenConverter FILENAME.sdtid -android  -o tokenfile.txt

I would like the script to run this command but prompt for the Filename.sdtid so that it can be entered and then processed.

I'm new to scripting so I'm not even sure where to begin with this.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
set /p var=Enter file name: 
TokenConverter %var% -android -o tokenfile.txt
```

try that. . . `;)`

Comment: That actually works very well.  Thank you! I just had to enter the location of where the token converter was located and where I wanted the output file to go.   **Would also know what I can add to the script so that after the token is generated, it will open an email(Outlook) and place it in to the body of the email?

Comment: nothing with batch... I might be able to incorporate vbscript, comment if you want me to.

Comment: If you could that would be amazing.

Comment: I added this to the script so if you could change this to a VB that you would be my savior:        @echo off
    set /p var=Enter file name:
    set /p user=Enter Username:
    T:\IT\IT-Installation\RSA_TokenConverter_Android\TokenConverterFiles_DO_NOT_TOUCH\TokenConverter %var% -android -o T:\IT\IT-Installation\RSA_TokenConverter_Android\TokenURLs\%user%.txt